# Margenes en interfaces de Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Mi duda es algo simple, ¿Hay alguna forma de colocar padx pero solo en un extremo? De manera que se genere un margen entre el Label y Text, pero no entre Text y Scrollbar.

Este sería un ejemplo del código:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()

frame=Frame(raiz, width=500, height=400)
frame.pack()

comentario_label=Label(frame, text="Comentario: ")
comentario_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=5)

comentario_text=Text(frame, width=16, height=5)
comentario_text.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=5)

scrollbar_comentario=Scrollbar(frame, command=comentario_text.yview)
scrollbar_comentario.grid(row=0, column=2)

raiz.mainloop()
```

¿Cómo haría para que entre `comentario_label` y `comentario_text` se presente un margen, pero no entre `comentario_text` y `scrollbar_comentario`?